# Ansible percent expand

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible

I have an ansible playbook which connects to a virtual machine via a non-standard ssh port (forwarded to localhost) and a different user than the host user (vagrant).

The ssh port is specified in the ansible inventory:

```
[vms]
localhost:2222
```

The username given on the command line to ansible-playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -i <inventory from above> <some playbook> -u vagrant
```

The communication with the VM works correctly, however, %p always expands to 22 and %r to the host username.

Consequently, I cannot flush the SSH connection (for the user's changed group membership to take effect) like this:

```
- name: flush the ssh connection
  command: ssh -o ControlPath="~/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -O stop {{inventory_hostname}}
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

Am I making a silly mistake somewhere? Alternatively, is there a different way to flush the SSH connection?

Comment: It seems I can correctly set the ControlPath this way: ControlPath="~/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-{{ansible_hostname}}-{{ansible_port}}-{{ansible_user}}" Perhaps the percent expands are not supposed to be used for this at all?

Answer (score 0):

The percent expand is not expanded by `ansible`, but by `ssh` later on.

<sub>Sorry, forgot to add the most important part</sub>

---

Using

```
command: ssh -o ControlPath=[...] -O stop {{inventory_hostname}}
```

will use default port, because you didn't specify it on the command-line. You would have to specify also the port to "flush" the connection this way:

```
command: ssh -o ControlPath=[...] -O stop -p {{inventory_port}} {{inventory_hostname}}
```

But I don't think it is needed. Ansible should clean up the connections when the playbook ends and I don't see any different reason why to do that.

Comment: It is needed if you change group membership for the user in some task and want the permissions to reflect that within the same playbook run.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It makes sense. Never mind, the mine proposal should do the job.